# matrix with its minors highlighted

Tags: matrices, tikz-matrix

I have to highlight the ith row and jth column which are removed from a matrix to form its minor as depicted in the picture[image]

My try is this, but I don't know how to highlight..

```
    \documentclass[preview, border=1pt, convert={outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand\x{\times}
\newcommand\y{\cellcolor{green!10}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    A = \det\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
    \rowcolor{red!20}
    a_{11}  & \ldots  & a_{1j} & \ldots & a_{1n} \\
    \ldots   & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
   \rowcolor{blue!20}
    a_{1j}  & \ldots   & a_{ij} & \ldots & a_{in} \\
    \ldots   & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
    a_{n1}  &  \ldots  & a_{nj} & \ldots & a_{nm}\\
  \end{array}\right)
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `tikzmark` you can declare stuff nodes, with `tikz` you can daw boxes around nodes, and `eso-pic` allows you to shuffle it on the background.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,fit}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\begin{document}
\[A = \det\left(\begin{array}{cccc} a_{11} & \tikzmarknode{a12}{a_{12}} & \ldots & a_{1n}  \\ 
    \tikzmarknode{a21}{a_{21}} & a_{22} & \ldots & \tikzmarknode{a2n}{a_{2n}}  \\
    \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
    a_{n1} & \tikzmarknode{an2}{a_{n2}} & \ldots & a_{nn}  \\
    \end{array}\right)\]
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[fit=(a12) (an2),draw=red,fill=red,fill opacity=0.2]{};
\node[fit=(a21) (a2n),draw=blue,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.2]{};
\end{tikzpicture}}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,fit}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\begin{document}
\[A = \det\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & \cdots & \tikzmarknode{a1i}{a_{1i}} & \cdots & a_{1n}  \\ 
    \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \reflectbox{$\ddots$} & \vdots \\
    \tikzmarknode{aj1}{a_{j1}} & \cdots & a_{ji} & \cdots & \tikzmarknode{ajn}{a_{jn}}  \\
    \vdots & \reflectbox{$\ddots$} & \ldots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    a_{n1} & \cdots &\tikzmarknode{ani}{a_{ni}} & \cdots & a_{nn}  \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\]
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[fit=(a1i) (ani),draw=red,fill=red,fill opacity=0.2]{};
\node[fit=(aj1) (ajn),draw=blue,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.2]{};
\end{tikzpicture}}      
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you cannot install the recent version of `tikzmark`, you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
% overleaf
\newcommand{\tikzmarknode}[3][]{\ifmmode%
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)]{\node[inner sep=0pt,#1](#2){$#3$};}%
\else%
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)]{\node[inner sep=0pt,#1](#2){#3};}%
\fi}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\begin{document}
\[A = \det\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & \cdots & \tikzmarknode{a1i}{a_{1i}} & \cdots & a_{1n}  \\ 
    \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \reflectbox{$\ddots$} & \vdots \\
    \tikzmarknode{aj1}{a_{j1}} & \cdots & a_{ji} & \cdots & \tikzmarknode{ajn}{a_{jn}}  \\
    \vdots & \reflectbox{$\ddots$} & \ldots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    a_{n1} & \cdots &\tikzmarknode{ani}{a_{ni}} & \cdots & a_{nn}  \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\]
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[fit=(a1i) (ani),draw=red,fill=red,fill opacity=0.2]{};
\node[fit=(aj1) (ajn),draw=blue,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.2]{};
\end{tikzpicture}}      
\end{document}
```

Comment: exactly that, thanks. When I compiling I get this:`! Undefined control sequence.  l.13 ...\begin{array}{cccc} a_{11} & \tikzmarknode
                                                  {a12}{a_{12}} & \ldots & a...`

Comment: @GiulianoMalatesta You need to update your TeX installation. `\tikzmarknode` has been added to the `tikzmark` library last year.

Comment: I've installed this texlive-tikzmark-8:svn44475-25.fc29.noarch. I can't install any newer version...btw in your code you inverted i with j, If I can't update the package I need to copy your image..

Comment: @GiulianoMalatesta Then do not load the `tikzmark` library and use `\newcommand{\tikzmarknode}[3][]{\ifmmode%
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)]{\node[inner sep=0pt,#1](#2){$#3$};}%
\else%
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)]{\node[inner sep=0pt,#1](#2){#3};}%
\fi}` instead. (I added an example as well.)

Comment: it produces only the matrix without the highlighting..

Comment: @GiulianoMalatesta You need to run it two or three times.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work inside a slide of a beamer presentation.

Comment: Likewise, this doesn't seem to work in a beamer presentation.